# how to run host commands from docker container?

Tags: docker, pacemaker, containers, crm

I have pacemaker cluster of hosts. And I have docker containers on each host. I want to run `crm_mon -Af1` command from container for underneath host. Basically, I want to get output of this command in docker container when I run that command in container. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this by doing ssh to host and run command over ssh from container.

Answer (score 0):

What resources from the host does this command need to run? Sort that out, then mount those resources into the container.

Comment: I can ssh to host and run command over ssh.